# Why is the length of this arc segment equal to the angle multiplied by one of the edges?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Why is it that the diagram says that the length of the arc is $R\,\Delta \theta$? $R$ is the length of one of the legs of the triangle and $\Delta \theta$ is the angle, but how do we get the length of the arc from that?

Also, later on, it says that $x = R\cos\theta$, so it seems like $R$ is being treated like the hypotenuse but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is in radians, then 
$\dfrac{\Delta \theta}{2 \pi} = \dfrac{\text{(arc-length)}}{2\pi R}$

Hence $\text{(arc-length)} = R \,\Delta \theta$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the circumference of a circle is $2\pi R$, which spans the full $2\pi$ arc angle. Thus,  proportionally, the arc-length corresponding to the angle $\Delta\theta$ Is $\frac{\Delta\theta}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi R= \Delta\theta R$.

The lengths $x$, $y$ and $R$ do form a right triangle, which leads to $x=R\cos\theta$ and $y=R\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

That's what radians are. The radian measure of an angle is the length of the corresponding arc of the **UNIT** circle. And "unit" circle means a circle of unit **radius**. I.e the radius is $1.$

If you make the radius $5$ times as big while keeping the same shape, you make all distances $5$ times as big, including the length of that arc.